# NumberFormatException while H2 db insert in a table with primary key type is string

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, h2

I am using Spring boot and h2 db for integration test case in microsoft-sql-server mode **jdbc:h2:~/sample;MODE=MSSQLServer**
While running test case Table has been created with proper data type

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TeamMemberType", schema = "SCH")
public class TeamMemberType {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "TeamMemberCode", unique = true, nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private String teamMemberCode;

  @Column(name = "Code")
  private String code;
}
```

Console:

```
Hibernate: create table SCH.TeamMemberType (TeamMemberCode varchar(255) identity not null, Code varchar(255))
```

while running test case it try to insert in db

```
insert INTO SCH.TeamMemberType (TeamMemberCode , Code) values ( 'Dev', 'Developer')
```

getting below exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'restTemplateBuilder' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder]:
>   Factory method 'restTemplateBuilder' threw exception; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration':
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4162ac5b]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jacksonHttpMessageConverter' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter]:
>   Factory method 'jacksonHttpMessageConverter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]:
>   Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory
>   method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'teamMemberRepository': Cannot create inner
>   bean '(inner bean)#202fd4c4' of type
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
>   bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#202fd4c4': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
>   argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing of
>   FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
>   Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/myprojectpath/target/test-classes/data.sql]: insert
>   INTO SCH.TeamMemberType (TeamMemberCode , Code) values ( 'Dev',
>   'Developer'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data
>   conversion error converting "Dev"; SQL statement:
>
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error
>   converting "Dev"; SQL statement: insert INTO SCH.TeamMemberType
>   (TeamMemberCode , Code) values ( 'Dev', 'Developer') Caused by:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Dev"

why h2 db knowingly `[TeamMemberCode varchar(255) identity]` converting "`Dev`" as `Number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` as you don't want Hibernate to generate ID for you, since your ID is a String. You have have to set it manually during each insert operation